# Add days to a specific date with a integer with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

This is my code below. I'm trying to do this in my code:

`input = 2014-02-09 + 5 days`, which should give `2014-02-14`, but instead I get the result: `2019-02-09` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="date" id="myDate" value="2014-02-09">
    <input type="number" id="number" value="5">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Try it </button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>

    <script>
      function myFunction() 
      {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        var y = document.getElementById("number").value;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
        var d = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
        document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = d;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I can get my desired result: `2014-02-09 + 5 days = 2014-02-14`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements this is what you want- just add some number on your selected date from datepicker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to display the date after changing the day of the month.</p>
  <input type="date" id="myDate" value="2014-02-09">
  <input type="number" id="number" value="5">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
  <p id="demo3"></p>

  <script>
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
      return this;
    };

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      var y = document.getElementById("number").value;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
      var newDate = new Date(x).addDays(parseInt(y));
      document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = newDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```